Alternative to Switch to set headers in Node Red
I have a NodeRed workflow that sends HTTP Requests to an API endpoint. Each message sent must authenticate based on where it is originating. I am currently using a switch element as a case to set a variable used to set the header in the request.
This results in the dreaded "Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" if a request takes more than an instant to process.

I am currently throttling the workflow to minimize this, as well as catching the error and dumping it back into the queue.
I am unsure of creating separate workflows and using a link would help this as I don't know if this strategy might have promise.

The switch + change node has nothing to do with this problem (unless there a multiple possible matches). What is the input? is it a HTTP-request/response pair missing from your image?

The Switch only sets msg.payload.NPI to a discreet value based on the payload. The HTTP-Request set a header of "customer" to this value.
This is the ONLY place in the entire workflow where a header is modified, so my thought was that this HAS to be where the error is coming from.

But if 2 of the conditions in the switch can match, then this will cause the input message to be duplicated (there is a setting to control this at the bottom of the switch node), so it will result in 2 http-requests, and then 2 messages reaching the http-response node, which will lead to the error mentions. There is not enough information in the question to make any further comment.

The data should never match two different outputs, but I have also enabled the "stopping checking after first match"  The errors still occur.
Looking closer, the error is actually happening when the response is sent back (http response node) which just returns the "OK" status 200 message. This is also in the header.
This appears to be the mistake! I am calling the API but I am not responsible for responding with a status message. DOH!
